# Can we add a Custom Button on a task Send an Email Page

Tags: custom-button

I have a requirement where i need to add a custom button (Say as enrolled) on a task Send Email page. Enrolled is a custom object . Once  we click on the custom button List of available enrolled details is shown .Select a relevant enrolled and click OK.The content of the enrolled details and there fields get populated in the body of the mail or as an attachment to the mail. Agent adds his text. Clicks send and the mail with Environment details is sent to the client.My concern is do we have an option to create  custom button on Send an email page.This send Email button is already coming from a visual force page.In the below given Screen Shot ,we are planning to have the button beside the cancel button as "Enrollement".
[image]

Any suggestions very much appreciated.

Comment: did you already google this? There are numerous solutions described. E.g. http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-email-url-hack-tutorial/

Comment: question is a bit unclear  - a screen shot of your goal would be helpful

Comment: @Guy,@ crop1645 :Thanks for your response.I have edited the question and given the info.Any Suggestion plz.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible at this time. There is an idea to enable this functionality here:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brdr

The current alternative is to replace the 'send email' button by a button pointing to a custom visualforce page. You also need to implement the 'send email' functionality on that page then.